# Security Module Menu

Tags: isis

I'm using this security module 
 `<groupId>org.isisaddons.module.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>isis-module-security-dom</artifactId>`
(isis version 1.16.2).

When I start the app the security function links(all roles, all packages.. ecc) are shown into the 'Other' menu(where I defined the 'unreferenced action'). I'm using a menubars.layout.xml, I can add other menus but I don't know how can I add security. Can someone help me? Thanks in advice

Comment: I look into sources and I found a solution. I don't think that is the best way but I manually added into my menubar.layout.xml the actions. For example:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look into sources and I found a solution. I don't think that is the best way but I manually added the actions into my menubar.layout.xml.For example:

```
<mb3:section>
   <mb3:serviceAction objectType="isissecurity.ApplicationUserMenu" id="findUsers">
                    <cpt:named>Find Users</cpt:named>
                </mb3:serviceAction>
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it.  It's also possible to download the menubars layout from the Prototyping menu, so you can use that as a starting point.